# jQuery-fileupload-rails fileupload is undefined on every attempt

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, jquery-fileupload-rails

I am trying to somewhat follow [this](http://railscasts.com/episodes/381-jquery-file-upload?autoplay=true) rails cast to get jQuery-fileuploader to work in rails with carrierwave. I have carrierwave and everything else working great but when I try to use jquery-fileupload-rails I keep getting the same error: `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'fileupload'`. This is the same when I try running `$(selector).fileupload()` in console.

Gemfile:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.16'

gem 'mysql2'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'rest-client'
gem 'will_paginate'
gem 'simple_form'
gem 'chronic'
gem 'nokogiri'

gem 'carrierwave'

group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails'
  gem 'coffee-rails'
  gem 'uglifier'
  gem 'jquery-fileupload-rails'
end
```

app/assets/javascripts/application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap
//= require bootstrap_ujs
//= require jquery-fileupload/basic
//= require_tree .
```

It also happens when I have `//= require jquery-fileupload` in the above.

I check the head and all the scripts are loading in the right order:

```
<script src="/assets/jquery.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap_ujs.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery-fileupload/vendor/jquery.ui.widget.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery-fileupload/jquery.iframe-transport.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery-fileupload/jquery.fileupload.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery-fileupload/basic.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/uploads.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/application.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

When analyzing the scripts in the dev console:

- <strike>The script `jquery-fileupload/basic.js` is just 5 blank lines... What should this be?</strike> [This](https://github.com/tors/jquery-fileupload-rails/blob/master/vendor/assets/javascripts/jquery-fileupload/basic.js) should be a blank file because all it contains is files to included by the assets pipeline.
- The `jquery-fileupload/jquery.fileupload.js` script is full of stuff but when I copy and paste this entire file into the console and hit enter it outputs:

`Object function ( selector, context ) { // The jQuery object is actually just the init constructor 'enhanced' return new jQuery.fn.init( selector, context, rootjQuery ); } has no method 'widget'`

I am running bundle install, uninstalling then reinstalling the gem and restarting the server (several times). After 5 hours of failure I started all over and tried again. It failed.

**UPDATE:**

If I copy paste the entire `jquery-fileupload/vendor/jquery.ui.widget.js` file into the console then copy paste the entire `jquery-fileupload/jquery.fileupload.js` into the console I don't get the error listed above and fileuplaod method is suddenly callable. This makes no sense to me because if it is included in the head in this order it should run in this order and be available when `$(selector).fileupload()` is called.

Answer (score 0):

With my update it is obvious to see that the assets are not being included correctly. I am almost positive this will be solved when the javascript files are all placed in the one large file and they will surely be executed in the correct order because they will be loaded together. I was able to solve the problem in the development environment by manually loading the scripts in the correct order like this:

```
jQuery ->
  $.getScript "/assets/jquery-fileupload/vendor/jquery.ui.widget.js", () ->
    $.getScript "/assets/jquery-fileupload/jquery.iframe-transport.js", () ->
      $.getScript "/assets/jquery-fileupload/jquery.fileupload.js", () ->
        $(selector).fileupload()
```

This is very inefficient because it makes three requests to the server waiting until the previous script loads before calling for the next. This should **NOT** be used in a production environment. I am not sure how to get the `application.js` to build out and be used in development but I will work on that. Once I can test the server in the production environment to see if it works like I expect I will update this answer and accept it if nobody has a better one yet.

I started an issue in github about this [here](https://github.com/tors/jquery-fileupload-rails/issues/58).

Comment: `//= require_directory .` ?

Comment: Should be `//require_tree .`, no?

Comment: @RichPeck `//= require_tree .` is actually what it should be. This should be a comment on the question. This is leftover from me messing around trying to fix it and I deleted the tree line and left this one by mistake. Thanks for pointing that out. It could have caused problems later.